# How to add the relationship for tittle of content type of other in view

Tags: views

How to add the relationship for tittle of content type of other in view of different content type.

[image]

Comment: Relation is based on database tables and fields of table

Comment: @Adi:so we cant add for tittle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to relate the two content types somehow. One of the most popular ways of doing it is using the module [entity_reference](http://drupal.org/project/entity_refrence).

After you install the module, create a field of type "entity_reference", and by then you should be able to add a relationship in your view using this field, allowing you to use all fields of the second content type on the primary content type's view.